# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic> flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http

tengan todos ustedes, estoy consultando una api de paises, pero al momento de mapearlo en flutter me aparece este error `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>`

estuve intentando con un curso de udemy, pero no tuve resultado alguno, ¿que puede ser este error o como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias y que tengan un excelente domingo

esto es lo que eh avanzado sin resultados.

**Este es mi modelo**

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<BodyCountry> bodyCountryFromJson(String str) => 
 List<BodyCountry>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => BodyCountry.fromJson(x)));

 String bodyCountryToJson(List<BodyCountry> data) => 
 json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

 class BodyCountry {
  BodyCountry({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.iso2,
});

int id;
String name;
String iso2;

factory BodyCountry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => BodyCountry(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    iso2: json["iso2"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "iso2": iso2,
 };
}
```

**Y este es mi provider**

```
class ApiCountry extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<BodyCountry> DisplayList = [];
  ApiCountry() {
     this.getOnDisplayCountry();
   }
  getOnDisplayCountry() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://api.countrystatecity.in/v1/countries/MX/states'),
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
      'X-CSCAPI-KEY':
          'XXX'
    });
final items = jsonDecode(response.body);
final data = BodyCountry.fromJson(items);
print(data);
```

}
}

Comment: Podrías agregar en tu pregunta, lo que te responde : "response.body" , hazle un print para ver que viene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el error que muestras es que el resultado que le envías a `BodyCountry.fromJson` es un List , pero ese método recibe un `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Leyendo tu código veo que es incorrecto el llamado que haces, eso es solo para transformar un objeto, pero tu deseas transformar una lista de objetos, también veo que tienes un método para eso (usaste https://quicktype.io/ creo).

Debes hacer la transformación así:

```dart
final data = bodyCountryFromJson(response.body);
```

Comment: si me funciono gracias :)